# OnClickListener to be executed only once

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

On an image, I want to set a click listener in order to performe an action after a click.

The code below is called more than once even after one click.

How can I prevent that?
(I have used either an onTouchListener but the result was the same...)

```
   Image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("DisplayImage", "on click");
            DisplayOneImage doi=new DisplayOneImage(DisplayImage.this,"Filtered image 1");
            doi.show();
        }
    });
```

The xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

>

<LinearLayout

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    >

    <!-- \/ \/ \/ \/ To be deleted Menu \/ \/ \/ \/ -->
    <!--include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" /-->
    <!-- /\ /\ /\ /\ To be deleted Menu /\ /\ /\ /\  -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/img_original"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Original Image:" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/initial_photo"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </ImageView>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Please post full code of this activity

Comment: Image1 is just imageview element in XML, yes the log is displayed multiple times and multiple Dialogs are displayed.

Comment: what if the user clicks after 5 min ? should the code run?

Comment: I updated the initial question adding the xml code

Comment: "The code below is called more than once even after one click." What do you mean by this? The listener is called more than once on a single click?

Comment: Please post a **complete** code example. This means that you should have a class and a method, just like you would in an actual .java file. I should be able to copy and paste the code you post here, add the appropriate imports and then compile it without any errors. This does **not** mean to post your entire Activity class. You should only post as much of it as is required to help us understand what you are asking about.

Comment: You should also describe the steps a user of your app will take and what the desired results are. Explain how what actually happens differs from what you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd set the `OnClickListener` to `null` inside the `onClick` method -as follows.

```
  Image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("DisplayImage", "on click");
        DisplayOneImage doi=new DisplayOneImage(DisplayImage.this,"Filtered image 1");
        doi.show();
        v.setOnClickListener(null);//Remove setOnClickListener
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

In case someone wants an `onClickListener` that can only be clicked every second (1000 milliseconds):

```
private boolean clicked = false;

element.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    if(!clicked){
        clicked = true;
        doSomething(v.getSomething());
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> clicked = false, 1000);
    }
});
```

You can of course change the 1000 to any number of milliseconds you'd like to see.

Answer (score 0):

Another, more invasive option

```
   Image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("DisplayImage", "on click");
        DisplayOneImage doi=new DisplayOneImage(DisplayImage.this,"Filtered image 1");

        doi.show();
        Image1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 Image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            boolean clicked = false;
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!clicked) {
                    Log.d("DisplayImage", "on click");
                    DisplayOneImage doi=new DisplayOneImage(DisplayImage.this,"Filtered image 1");
                    doi.show();
                    clicked = true;
                }
            }
    });
```

Comment: It does not work, I've already tried it but after the first click and pressing the back button it does not respond to another click.